# String split, filter and join in single line java 8

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I have string  which I would like to split by comma and check for a specific word in each one and then trim and then join it to create new string

Input:

```
"UC_Admin, Internal, UC_Reg, US_Admin"
```

Desired Output:

```
 "UC_Admin,UC_Reg"
```

What I tried is:

```
Arrays.stream("UC_Admin,Internal,UC_Reg,US_Admin".split(","))
      .filter(role -> role.contains("UC").join(",");
```

Comment: it did not seem to work, is there better way?

Comment: What does "did not seem to work mean"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `Collectors.joining(",")` here. Also note that for the trim operation you can merely use the `map` operator.

```
String result = Arrays.stream("UC_Admin,Internal,UC_Reg,US_Admin".split(","))
    .filter(role -> role.contains("UC"))
    .map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

A much better approach is given below. This should outperform the former solution for a large data set. However, I have not conducted any benchmark to prove that.

```
private static final Pattern COMMA = Pattern.compile(",");

String result = COMMA.splitAsStream("UC_Admin,Internal,UC_Reg,US_Admin")
    .filter(role -> role.contains("UC"))
    .map(String::trim)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: I also need to trim each one